# Removing single and double quotes from BigQuery using regexp_extract

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I'm a total noob with regexp. All I want to do is to remove the single and double quotes from a string in BigQuery. I can remove the single and double quotes at the beginning of the string, but not the end:

`SELECT regexp_extract(foo, r'\"new_foo\":\"(.*?)\"') AS new_foo 
FROM [mybq:Schema.table]`

All I get is Null but without `regexp_extract` I have expected results. Help is appreciated.

Comment: So, the problem is that I have either a single or a double quote sometimes at the front, sometimes at the front, sometimes at both ends and sometimes  at neither. Here is an example: 
'atom"
bomb
crazy'
"duck''
'elephant
fox''
"giraffe"
''hippo''
''igloo

Answer (score 2):

Try something like below

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(foo, r'([\'\"])', '') AS new_foo 
FROM [mybq:Schema.table]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select replace(word,'"','') as word
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex expression should be like `/["']/g`

And your are using different method to get the expected result. Try [REGEXP_REPLACE('orig_str', 'reg_exp', 'replace_str')](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#regexp_replace)

Something like this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(word, /["']/g, '')AS new_foo 
FROM [mybq:Schema.table]
```